# Question about vibrating string problem,Sturm-Liouville problem

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, sturm-liouville

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XpRGO.png)

**I'm stuck on how to simplify the BC condition. I get '(0)=(0); '(1)=(1). How can I connect this to question?
Bty, what's Sturm-Liouville problem for (x)?**

Answer (score 0):

The eigenvalue problem for your equation in $x$ is
$$
                      X_{\lambda}''(x) = -\lambda X_{\lambda}(x) \\
                       X_{\lambda}'(0)=X_{\lambda}(0),\\
                       X_{\lambda}'(1)=X_{\lambda}(1).
$$
Part of the problem in solving such an equation is that $X_{\lambda}$ is unique only up to a multiplicative constant, which is something remedied by choosing a particular normalization. To this end, replace the condition at $x=0$ with
$$
               X_{\lambda}'(0)=1=X_{\lambda}(0).
$$
Without trying to satisfy the right endpoint condition, the unique $X_{\lambda}$ has the form
$$
               X_{\lambda}(x)=\cos(\sqrt{\lambda}x)+\frac{\sin(\sqrt{\lambda}x)}{\sqrt{\lambda}}.
$$
At $\lambda=0$, the above takes on the correct limiting form,
$$
             X_{0}(x) = 1 + x.
$$
In order for $\lambda$ to be an eigenvalue, it is necessary and sufficient that
$$
                   X_{\lambda}'(1)=X_{\lambda}(1),
$$
which leads to the eigenvalue equation
$$
          -\sqrt{\lambda}\sin(\sqrt{\lambda})+\cos(\sqrt{\lambda})=\cos(\sqrt{\lambda})+\frac{\sin(\sqrt{\lambda})}{\sqrt{\lambda}}.
$$
$\lambda=0$ is not an eigenvalue. So, after excluding this case multiplying by $\sqrt{\lambda}$ give an equivalent equation:
$$
          (\sqrt{\lambda}+1/\sqrt{\lambda})\sin(\sqrt{\lambda})=0, \\
           (\lambda+1)\sin(\sqrt{\lambda})=0.
$$
The eigenvalues are
$$
        \lambda = -1,\pi^2,(2\pi)^2,\cdots.
$$
The corresponding eigenfunctions are
$$
   X_{-1}(x) = \cosh(x)+\sinh(x)=e^{x}, \\
X_{n^2\pi^2}(x)= \cos(n\pi x)+\frac{\sin(n\pi x)}{n\pi},\;\; n=1,2,3,\cdots.
$$